# What happened to the Planck charge on Wikipedia?

Tags: charge, units, history, physical-constants, metrology

Wikipedia [used to have](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Planck_units&oldid=1007411999) a nice article about the Planck units, with [contributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Planck_units&type=revision&diff=1007411999&oldid=1007304812) made directly by [Don Page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don_Page_(physicist)).

I recently visited [the current article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_units) and the Planck charge kind of disappeared. I also saw that [some dispute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Talk:Planck_units/Archive_4#Named_Planck_units) took place a year ago, in which some editors were arguing that the Planck charge is fringe science and should not be mentioned in the article.

Is the Planck charge used only in fringe science?

Comment: Probably opinion based but also not really a physics question.  Wikipedia pages have their own edit history and talk pages where you'll get all the publicly available information.

Comment: see the answers here  https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/186656/ . No it is not fringe science.