# What is the dimension of the weak gauge field couplin constant NOT in natural units?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, units, dimensional-analysis, physical-constants

What is the dimension of g and g', NOT in natural units, but in terms of mass, length, time, and permittivity?

Comment: Coupling constants are dimensionless

Comment: @dukwon Should probably be an answer, with maybe a short explanation as to where the units come in when we do calculations.

Comment: @dukwon Coupling constants are **not** (generically) dimensionless. The gauge coupling constant in $d\neq 4$ is dimensionful, and so is e.g. $\lambda \phi^6$ in $d=4$.

Comment: [Related](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/147603/are-there-planck-units-for-weak-or-strong-charge-similar-to-the-electromagnet).

Comment: Your answer told me what the convention you are used to using is. Personally, I use a set of dimensions which I find infinitely superior to any others, past or present, so I am obliged to translate everything I read into them. Now I understand how to translate yours.

Comment: I had not appreciated the core of the question was justifying the Lorentz-Heaviside rationalized system. I am used to using them in this field, like anybody else, because, as explained, other systems involve quantities ***never used*** in HEP experiments; any expectation they are is erroneous/misplaced. I assumed I put that canard to bed in my 500lb gorilla paragraph... Have you looked at the questions addressing that point? The intersection of HEP with engineering is remarkably narrow.

Comment: I am not an engineer and I don't care whether there is an intersection of HEP and engineering or not.

Answer (score 2):

In natural units (first: there is an overwhelming *reason* and method in their madness!) these are both related to the electric charge *e* through the [Weak mixing angle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weinberg_angle). See the triangle figure:
$$
g=e/\sin\theta_W, \qquad g'= e/\cos\theta_w, \\
 \sin^2 \theta _\text{W}=1-(m_\text{W}/m_\text{Z})^2=0.2223(21).
$$

All you need then is to convert the natural units *e* to the engineering units **e** you are seeking through the dimensionless [fine structure constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fine-structure_constant), 
$$
α= {\mathbf{e}} ^2 /4π \epsilon_0 ħc =  0.0072973525664(17) ,
$$
or something... Insert your new/accurate CODATA values at your leisure.

In natural units, $\alpha = e^2/ 4 \pi$ since *1=ε<sub>0</sub> = c = ħ = 1*, so you redimensionalize the above *g* and *g'* by multiplying them with $\sqrt{\epsilon_0 ħc}$.

At the core of your curiosity question, however is the 500lb gorilla question of ***why*** ? The weak interactions are microscopic, and you'll never monitor something about them with your ammeter, galvanometer, whatever. The microscopic world of HEP has precious few conceptual linkages with engineering.

In an experiment, you will probably use the SM to compute lifetimes, in ***seconds***, or cross sections in ***barns*** ($10^{−28} m^2$), etc, in which the dimensions of the couplings would be in the way---they are merely intermediate computational devices. (Your comment appears to trace to advantages of various systems in metrology, where HEP has little to offer.)

All you'd need do is throw in the suitable powers of *ħ* and *c* in redimensionalizing.

For any intuition, stay natural and compare with your yardstick *e*=0.30282212....